# ASP.Net C# reference to element on Site.master returns: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've found threads solving this issue within Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs, but applying those solutions to my problem don't fix my issue. None of them are helpful in this context:

I'm trying to access an element on my Site.master page within Default.aspx.cs. I want to hide this element if a certain condition isn't met. However, I cannot reference any elements within my Site.master page (either within Default.aspx.cs OR Site.master.cs)

Code:

Site.master:

```
<li><a runat="server" id="editLink" href="~/Edit">Edit</a></li>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
MasterPage master = this.Master;
Control linkControl = master.FindControl("editLink");
linkControl.Visible = false;
```

I've also tried:

Site.master:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <li><a runat="server" id="editLink" href="~/Edit">Edit</a></li>
</asp:Panel>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
((Panel)Master.FindControl("Panel1")).Visible = false;
//or..
//Panel testPanel = ((Panel)Master.FindControl("Panel1"));
//Panel1.Visible = false;
```

I don't know where to start. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've tried to apply resolutions from:

[ASP.NET - Accessing Master Page elements form the Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461911/asp-net-accessing-master-page-elements-form-the-content-page)

[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Specifically from the first:

adding the following to Default.aspx

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Site.master" %>
```

adding the following to Default.aspx.cs

```
Panel testPanel = (Panel)Master.FindControl("Panel1");       
testPanel.Visible = true;
```

The above code is the suggested fix for the first thread, but I get the same error. The second thread seemed to suggest I was referencing the element before it was created thus returning the nullreferenceexception error, but I do not believe this is the case. Ultimately, I do not understand enough to utilize those threads.

**EDIT**

Site.master MCVE:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<form id="wrapForm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">Test Text</asp:Panel>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs MCVE:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel testPanel = (Panel)Master.FindControl("Panel1"); 
    testPanel.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Other possible duplicate: [ASP.NET - Accessing Master Page elements form the Content Page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/461911/1260204)

Comment: You haven't shown the context of where the control is within a master page. Is it in another control? It helps to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe your development webserver is still loading the old assemblies? Could be an idea to shut down the server entirely and rebuild/run.

Comment: @mason I attempted to add an MCVE - stripped everything from Site.master and included just the Page_Load method from Default.aspx.cs. Please let me know if I've done this incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Igor Edited, as I do not believe either of those threads help - I'd attempted to utilize the solutions in those specific threads and they do not seem to help

Comment: which is null at runtime? `Master`, or `testPanel`? could you include the markup of Default.aspx as well?

Comment: `MasterType` <= shouldn't that be `Reference` as per [ASP.NET - Accessing Master Page elements form the Content Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461911/asp-net-accessing-master-page-elements-form-the-content-page) ? So `<%@ Reference virtualpath="~/Site.master" %>`

Comment: Your MCVE is helpful (although still not complete). Why do you have the panel inside of a `ContentPlaceHolder`? Does your page have an `asp:Content` that corresponds to `MainContent`?

Comment: @Igor That was it. Thank you very much! (can I mark comments as solutions?)

Comment: @mason the ContentPlaceHolder is referenced within Default.aspx and all other pages, so I don't have to add a header every time. I must have organized this in an odd way - changing my reference to the Master page made it so I can reference the panel, so now I'll start researching best practices for organization. Thank you!

Comment: Content in a content place holder will not be included in the resulting page if the content page has a Content control corresponding to that content place holder. The content from the content page will overwrite it.

Comment: @Ninjutstu - Thanks for the update. No, you can't mark a comment as answer but I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MasterType` <= that should be `Reference` as per [ASP.NET - Accessing Master Page elements form the Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461911/asp-net-accessing-master-page-elements-form-the-content-page) ?

```
<%@ Reference virtualpath="~/Site.master" %>
```